# What role do modules play in writing code that is less memory-intensive?

Tags: vba

At work, I'm venturing into the world of VBA to try to make a spreadsheet template, which will run a report when a command button is clicked.

On several occasions I have encountered an "Out of Memory" run-time error, which has been easily fixed by jigging with the code using combinations of suggestions by other users on this site!

However, I am now curious about how to make codes less memory-intensive. In particular, do modules help make code less memory-intensive and, if so, how should I use them effectively in this regard? For example, should I assign a `Sub` to each module or would that be overkill?

I'm new to VBA so any/all help and criticism is very welcome!

Comment: Nope, they're just for organizational purposes. Having code split over multiple modules doesn't affect performance at all.

Comment: Modules is just a structure to have the code more readable and more easy to do support , dont impact in performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: None whatsoever.

---

An "out of memory" error has many reasons to occur, none of which relate to how many modules your code is organized in. Because that's all modules are: an organizational tool at your disposal.

It is completely impossible to diagnose an "out of memory" error without knowing anything about what the code is doing: `<meta>` you would have to narrow down the problem to a particular specific piece of code before you can ask about it on this site (dumping a whole module and asking "what's wrong with this code?" isn't going to fly) `</meta>`

Look for very, *very* large arrays, clipboard operations perhaps. Maybe you're running a loop that's attempting to create and store a bajillion `New` large objects - could be pretty much anything... just not the number of modules.

---

> *should I assign a `Sub` to each module or would that be overkill?*

As with many things, the answer is "it depends". Once you've familiarized yourself with the language, and start learning about Object-Oriented Programming (OOP), you'll come across design guidelines and principles that strongly advocate towards keeping public interfaces as simple as possible: adhering to the *Interface Segregation Principle* (the "I" of "SOLID") means that this is a perfectly complete and acceptable class module to have:

```
'@Interface IComparable
'@ModuleDescription("Defines a generalized type-specific comparison method that a class implements to order or sort its instances.")
Option Explicit

'@Description("Compares the current instance with another object of the same type and returns an integer that indicates whether the current instance precedes (-1), follows (1), or occurs in the same position in the sort order (0) as the other object.")
Public Function CompareTo(ByVal other As Object) As Integer
End Function
```

But that's well beyond beginner-level procedural programming concepts.

> *[...] which will run a report when a command button is clicked.*

That command button could be an ActiveX button, or a `Shape` object that's attached to a macro. Assuming it's ActiveX, the worksheet's code-behind might look like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub RunSalesReportButton_Click()
    SalesReportMacro.CreateWeeklyReport
End Sub
```

And then you can have a `SalesReportMacro` standard module that might start out like this:

```
'@ModuleDescription("A macro that generates the weekly sales report.")
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

'@Descrition("Generates the weekly sales report.")
Public Sub CreateWeeklyReport()
    If Not RefreshSalesData Then Exit Sub
    CreatePivotReport
End Sub
```

The `Public` procedure at the top has a very high *abstraction level*: it's easy to tell at a glance what the procedure is going to be doing, because the lower-level procedures have meaningful names that tell us exactly what's going on. These lower-level procedures would be right underneath:

```
Private Function RefreshSalesData() As Boolean
    Dim reportWeek As String
    reportWeek = PromptForReportWeek
    If Not IsNumeric(reportWeek) Then Exit Function

    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    AdjustDataConnectionCommand reportWeek
    RefreshSalesData = True

CleanExit:
    Exit Function
CleanFail:
    MsgBox "Could not refresh the data for week " & reportWeek & ".", vbExclamation
    Resume CleanExit
End Function
```

And the deeper you go, the lower the abstraction level becomes:

```
Private Function PromptForReportWeek() As String
    Dim currentWeek As Integer
    currentWeek = GetCurrentWeekNumber
    PromptForReportWeek = InputBox("Please specify week#", "Generate Report", currentWeek)
End Function

Private Function GetCurrentWeekNumber()
    GetCurrentWeekNumber = 42 'todo
End Function

Private Sub AdjustDataConnectionCommand(ByVal weekNumber As String)
    With ThisWorkbook.Connections(1).OLEDBConnection
        .CommandText = "dbo.WeeklySalesReport " & weekNumber
        .Refresh
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CreatePivotReport()
    'todo
End Sub
```

---

Procedures (`Sub`, `Function`, and others you'll discover in due time) should have *one* purpose, and be kept as short and focused on that one task as possible. By doing that, you make it easier to later *refactor* your code - say in 2 months you need to add another ActiveX button for a new `CreateWeeklyInventoryReport` macro: there's a good chance that this new report will also need to `PromptForReportWeek` - if that functionality is already well-abstracted into its own scope, you can more easily just remove/cut it from that module, add a new `CalendarParameterPrompt` module (which... might end up only having *that procedure* for a while.. until you need a good place to put a similar `PromptForReportMonth` function), add/paste it in there, make it `Public`, and invoke it from any other macro/module.

Doing this instead of massive omnipotent procedures that know everything and do everything (and eventually stop compiling because they got so large VBA refuses to compile them), will spare you *lots* of headaches in the near future.

Comment: Thank you kindly Mathieu! There's certainly a lot of food for thought here and I'm very grateful for your suggestions.

For clarification: Are different abstraction levels characterised by their purpose, where lower abstraction levels are the building blocks for implementing higher abstraction levels?